# How to set starting number for integers in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am trying to submit a payment charge. I made my table and have orders in them with `order_id` starting from one. Here is my schema:

```
  create_table "payments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "payment_id"
    t.integer  "order_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.string   "payment_type"
    t.index ["order_id"], name: "index_payments_on_order_id", using: :btree
  end
```

The payment provider requires at least 10 digits in `order_id`. How would I migrate this to make my data start from something like 1000000`890`? Is there any way to change where the data increments from?

Comment: `ALTER SEQUENCE order_id_seq RESTART WITH 1000000890` and `UPDATE payments set order_id = order_id + 1000000` ?..

Comment: @VaoTsun why don't you post this as an answer, so people see that the question was answered?

Comment: @VaoTsun should i run this as a migration?

Comment: @meta My suggestion is pure SQL - I don't know if it fits OP needs

Comment: @NooBskie I'm not familiar with ruby - sorry. The above are SQL statements that in my understanding will do what you need. I don't know how to "turn" them a migration commands

Comment: Is `order_id` a foreign key that identifies a row in an `orders` table or an identifier for your payment provider (unrelated to your database)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I don't know how to turn the below a ruby migration, I'll just leave it as SQL commands to achieve the goal in the post:

Let's say your highest existing order_id is 890, then to set last value of its sequence so the next default value would be 1000000891, you have to:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE order_id_seq RESTART WITH 1000000890;
```

and to deal with existing values, you need to update them:

```
UPDATE payments set order_id = order_id + 1000000000;
```

Of course it should work if you did not reach 1000000 yourself (which is reflected in "Let's say your highest existing order_id is 890")

Comment: you can just run raw sql in the rails migration with the `execute` command. That's it ;)